# MySQL / Percona UPDATE performance when using min or max in joined table

Tags: php, mysql, join

The following query ran in 5s:

```
UPDATE table1 li inner JOIN (SELECT min(c.id_table1 ) as id
        FROM table2 l
                JOIN table3 c ON c.id_table2 = l.id AND c.date = '2016-01-01'
                JOIN bloc_table b ON b.id = l.id_bloc_table and b.reference = '2568548'
                JOIN code_client a ON a.id_code_client = c.id_code_client AND ( a.label = 'C' OR a.label LIKE 'C %')
        WHERE c.hour IS NULL) t1
        ON li.id_ligne_c = t1.id
        SET li.hour = '11:18'
```

Here is the explain:

id  select_type table   partitions  type possible_keys  key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   UPDATE  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    no matching row in const table
2   DERIVED l   NULL    index   PRIMARY,unique_table2,fk_table2_bloc_table  fk_table2_bloc_table    4   NULL    2719403 100.00  Using index
2   DERIVED c   NULL    eq_ref  fk_table3_table2,key_table3_1,key_table3_6,fk_table3_code_client    fk_table3_table2    4   mydb.l.id_table2    1   5.00    Using where
2   DERIVED b   NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY,unique_bloc_table,key_bloc_table,fk_bloc_table_client_file  PRIMARY 4   mydb.l.id_bloc_table    1   5.00    Using where
2   DERIVED a   NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY,unique_code_client_libelle  PRIMARY 1   mydb.c.id_code_client   1   5.00    Using where
2   DERIVED r   NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY,unique_client_item  PRIMARY 2   mydb.b.id_client_file   1   100.00  Using where

While the following ran in 0.00001s:

```
UPDATE table1 li inner JOIN (SELECT c.id_table1 as id
        FROM table2 l
                JOIN table3 c ON c.id_table2 = l.id AND c.date = '2016-01-01'
                JOIN bloc_table b ON b.id = l.id_bloc_table and b.reference = '2568548'
                JOIN code_client a ON a.id_code_client = c.id_code_client AND ( a.label = 'C' OR a.label LIKE 'C %')
        WHERE c.hour IS NULL) t1
        ON li.id_ligne_c = t1.id
        SET li.hour = '11:18'
```

Here is the explain:

id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  b   NULL    ref PRIMARY,unique_bloc_table,key_bloc_table,fk_bloc_table_client_file  key_bloc_table  4   const   1   100.00  NULL
1   SIMPLE  r   NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY,unique_client_item  PRIMARY 2   mydb.b.id_client_file   1   100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  a   NULL    range   PRIMARY,unique_code_client_libelle  unique_code_client_libelle  14  NULL    1   100.00  Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  l   NULL    ref PRIMARY,unique_table2,fk_table2_bloc_table  unique_table2   4   mydb.b.id_bloc_table    6   100.00  Using index
1   SIMPLE  c   NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY,fk_table3_table2,key_table3_1,key_table3_6,fk_table3_code_client    fk_table3_table2    4   mydb.l.id_table2    1   5.00    Using where
1   UPDATE  li  NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   mydb.c.id_ligne_c   1   100.00  NULL

The only difference is the use of the "MIN" as a way to only update 1 row at a time in case there are many occurrences of the same client, placing different items in the same order.

I m using percona DB v5.7.17-11

How can I achieve the same performance (0.00001s Vs 5s) by selecting only 1 row at a time?

All the fields used in joins or in where clause have been indexed.

Thanks

Comment: Add explain plans for this queries `explain %query%`

Comment: @MaxP. , I added it but it does not seem too readable as is.